Firebase custom events are not sent on Unity IOS
I have problems with Firebase Analytics.
It works normally on Android, but not on iOS.
I found that Firebase Analytics framework can be linked only statically.
github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk
So the solution is to use
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
But in this case I have other frameworks (Applovin, FB), which crash when linking statically.
The next solution would be manually/statically add the Firebase to XCode.
But this also leads to errors (or maybe I have done some wrong things).
What is the correct way of manually adding Firebase Analytics framework?
Should I use .xcframework or just take .framework from .xcframework?
I will appreciate some other suggestion also.
I have tried different things.

Updated GoogleService-info.plist
Enabling analytics manually from the code
Updated FirebaseUnity SDK version from 11.6.0 to 12.+
Tried a separate empty project with only Firebase Analytics, here I found that dynamic linking doesn't work even for that simple project.

